# Undefined Index Weather

Tags: php, json

So I made this script, basically a command.

What it does is, a user defines the command "weather" with $arg which $arg is whatever that's being said. and then decodes the json that get's produced and then sends the packet with only two things from the json. However it says that "location" and "temperature" are undefined.

Could someone help me fix this? The packet get's sent properly but it doesn't show the location or the temperature when the packet is sent. The packet sm = send message.

here is the code

```
if($cmd == 'weather'){
$file = file_get_contents('http://weather3.pricop.info/api.php?city=' . $arg);
$weather = json_decode($file, true);
$user->sendPacket("%xt%sm%-1%0%" . " Temperature for " . $weather["location"] . "%" . " will be " . $weather["temperature"]  . "%"); 
}
```

Comment: Please show `var_dump($file);` - we can't really debug why your JSON isn't decoding right without seeing the JSON ;-)

Comment: http://prntscr.com/1io71v

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response looks like:

```
{"apiVersion":"1.0", "data":{ "location":"Pascagoula, MS", "temperature":"79", "skytext":"Mostly Cloudy", "humidity":"84", "wind":"6", "date":"2013-07-31", "day":"Wednesday" } }
```

The returned data has the location attribute inside of a data attribute so you must reference. it as

```
$weather["data"]["location"];
```

and

```
$weather["data"]["temperature"];
```